# SQL Query Problems (Correctness check)

Tags: sql

Tables:

– Beers (name, manufacturer)
– Bars (name, address, license)
– Sells (bar,beer, price)
– Drinkers (name, address, phone)
– Likes (drinker, beer)
– Frequents (drinker, bar)
– Friends (drinker1, drinker2)

Tasks:

1. Find all beers liked by two or more drinkers
2. Find all beers liked by three or more drinkers
3. Find all beers liked by friends of Anna
4. Find all bars that sell a beer that is cheaper than all beers sold by the bar "99    Bottles"

Query #1:

```
SELECT x name  
FROM Beers x, Drinkers y, Likes s    
WHERE y.name=s.drinker and s.beer=x.name
GROUP BY x.name    
HAVING COUNT(s.drinker) >= 2;
```

Query #2:

Same as the previous

Query #3.

```
SELECT x name
FROM Beers x, Friends y, Drinkers z, Likes p  
WHERE z.name = "Anna" 
  AND z.name = y.drinker1   
  AND y.drinker2 = p.drinker 
  AND p.beer = x.name;
```

Query #4:

```
SELECT x.name
FROM Bars x, Sells y
WHERE x.name = y.bar 
  AND SOME(SELECT y.price) < ALL(SELECT t.price
                                 FROM Sells t
                                 WHERE t.bar = "99 bottles");
```

I am a little bit hesitant about the last one. Am I allowed to use SOME in that way? Can I put create a sub-query by using outer variables in the select clause?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Yes, everyone tells me that all the time as soon as I stepped on SQL, but that's what my teacher is using. He told us that we will learn about that sintax later in the course.

Answer (score 1):

**3. Find all beers liked by friends of Anna:**

There are 2 main issues with your answer:

- The query may return the same beer name more than once in certain scenarios
- You will miss some cases, because "Anna" may appear in either `drinker1` or `drinker2` column of the Friends table

Here'a sample solution using explicit `JOIN`'s:

```
SELECT x.name
FROM Beers
WHERE b.name IN (
    SELECT l.beer
    FROM Likes l
        INNER JOIN Friends f
            ON l.drinker = f.drinker1
    WHERE f.drinker2 = "Anna"

    UNION

    SELECT l.beer
    FROM Likes l
        INNER JOIN Friends f
            ON l.drinker = f.drinker2
    WHERE f.drinker1 = "Anna"
)
```

**4. Find all bars that sell a beer that is cheaper than all beers sold by the bar "99 Bottles":**

You are using SOME and ALL incorrectly;

- We never use these keywords on **both** sides of a comparison operator
- The expression inside `SOME` or `ALL` must be a complete sub-query (`SELECT y.price` is not a valid expression)

Here'a sample solution using `IN` AND `MIN`:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM Bars b
WHERE b.name IN (

    SELECT s.bar
    FROM Sells s
    WHERE s.price <
    (
        SELECT MIN(price)
        FROM Sells
        WHERE bar = "99 bottles"
    )

)
```

Comment: Hello Serge, thank you so much for your answer; however, the sintax that my teacher is using is different. I know that's outdated, but the mid-term is based on that sintax. He told us that eventually he would teach us the sintax you are using. Can u please provide feedback about my work?